# How to break a too long type docstring

Tags: python, types, pycharm, docstring

I have a python method which receives multiple arguments and returns multiple arguments. I specify their types, but the line is too long. Pycharm doesn't allow me to break it into 2 lines, even when I use a "".

How should I break the line (aside from doing `import pyspark.sql.DataFrame as something_shorter`)?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark

def my_metod(sdf1, sdf2, df1, df2):
    # type: (pyspark.sql.DataFrame, pyspark.sql.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame) -> (dict, str, str, dict, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame)

    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a backslash `\`.

```
pyspark.sql.DataFrame, pyspark.sql.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame)  \
-> (dict, str, str, dict, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame)
```

If I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Yes, but somehow pycharm highlights it in red and thinks it's an error.